# grub-install error while moving /boot partition to /

Tags: server, partitioning

```
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev                                 252G     0  252G   0% /dev
    tmpfs                                 51G  1.9G   49G   4% /run
    /dev/md7                             438G   32G  384G   8% /
    tmpfs                                252G  884K  252G   1% /dev/shm
    tmpfs                                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs                                252G     0  252G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/md6                             453M  200M  230M  47% /boot
```

I want to move `/boot` to `/dev/md7`  and  remount `/dev/md6` on `/test`.

I followed the instructions posted earlier here.
I got this error while running:

```
grub-install
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: install device isn't specified.
/boot is in /
/dev/md7                            438G   32G  384G   8% /
```

Comment: x86_64
4.4.0-31-generic
Linux sandstone 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux..however when i run grub-install i get error  grub-install
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: install device isn't specified.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details. The command [`grub-install`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/grub-install) requires a parameter – the drive to be installed to.

Comment: @Melebius i have edited the comment. do i have to do grub-install /dev/md7 or grub-install /dev/sda.. also once i move /boot under /  does it needs to be mounted as /boot

Comment: I am sorry, I don’t have any experience with doing this on `mdX` which is probably supposed to be RAID. You should note that in your question (including tags) and wait for someone experienced to help. It’s easy to get an unbootable system while partitioning.